# Should [rough-idle] be distinct from [hunting-idle]?

Tags: discussion

Just finished reviewing this question

[92 Honda Accord keeps revving up and down](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/51768/675)

I'm wondering if there should be a [hunting-idle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hunting-idle) tag that is distinct from [rough-idle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rough-idle). Here is a similar question with the latter tag:

[2005 Honda Accord 4cyl revving idle when warm](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/24145/675)

The motivation for making a distinction between the two is higher resolution of symptom classification.

I went ahead and created the tag but if the difference is deemed too minor then please let me know and/or revert the change.

Comment: Fine with both tags, But should we have idle-rough and idle-hunting as they are then possibly more easily found? Would this then apply to other tags? Is it worth the effort of change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our other mods can correct me if they feel otherwise, but it's always been my premise we should use tags which make sense. If a tag makes sense, you cannot have too many of them. They are metadata which can allow others to find things on the site as well as help classify issues for future reference. You've been active on this stack long enough I believe most people on here who know you will have no issues with you creating a tag which you believe makes sense. It makes sense to me, so looks like we have a winner.